# Large Microsoft Word file won't save or export to pdf

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-word-2010

I a word file over 200 pages containing my thesis, and out of lack of a better method I am using the subdocuments feature. My subdocuments are pretty massive because they contain a lot of excel plots and figures, which is why I had to split them up into different documents in the first place. I am trying to format and export my thesis to pdf, so I have combined them all in to the master file, but the sections with lots of plots won't export. When I save as pdf I am doing it piece by piece since it seems since it doesn't seem to like large exports. But even when I try to export just one or two pages at a time that contain figures and plots word gives me an error saying "The export failed due to an unexpected error".

Any help with this would be appreciated since I am pulling my hair out trying to get it work.

Comment: Have you tried using a print driver to export to PDF?

Comment: Can you print the document? If so, you might be able to work around the MS Word export problems by printing to a PDF or a PostScript ("easily" convertible to PDF) printer and see if that works. Another alternative is to add (or take out) the Adobe PDF add-in, since that could avoid (or exercise) the bug giving you problems. Unfortunately, the symptom, i.e. being unable to export to PDF, does not have a single diagnosis and remedy.

Comment: Just to be clear, by "printing to a PDF or a PostScript ... printer" I meant using a printer device that creates a PDF or PostScript file.

Comment: No I thought about that, but I don't have any software currently installed to allow me to print to pdf. I think I am just going to keep them in their separate documents and just set each individual document to start at the right page number and heading sections. I have been working on this and it seems much easier than using a massive file. Hopefully the individual files will be able to save as pdfs easier and then I can combine them into one PDF document afterwards. This is a pretty frustrating problem though, so I would still appreciate any helpful hints in case I run into this again.